# Xcode 6 quit unexpectedly after I press the output windows

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, crash

I'm new to mac and Xcode 6 and I was trying to code in C++ using Xcode. However, Xcode always crash when I press the output windows after build success, even the Hello World code crashes! >.<
Below is the video of how Xcode crash. Please help! T.T
http://youtu.be/-A46h9KbXpg

Comment: What version of OS X and Xcode ? Is it a legal Mac or a hackintosh ? Can you post the crash log ?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use Xcode in full screen mode! It tends to crash when in full screen. This is a known bug that Apple hasn't yet fixed.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer! I can use Xcode in windowed mode now. :-)